# Can't use "?" in URL because .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, get

I have the following code into my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -MultiViews
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteBase /testUrl/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]
```

Then I catch the params using $_GET['page'] method.

This works:

localhost/testUrl/param1/param1

This DOES'NT works

http://localhost/testUrl/param1/param1?newparam=test&nextparam=test1

BUT THIS WORKS:

http://localhost/testUrl/param1/param1&newparam=test&nextparam=test1

I need to make working the 2nd example... with /param1/param2?newparam=etc

Any tips? Thank you so much guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because your rewrite rule doesnt include the QSA flag witch tells apache to append query string.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

to read more about rewrite mod flags go to - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html